# Is there some fast way to dump an ADO recordset into a new MS ACCESS table?

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access-2016

We have a SQL Server Backend with MS ACCESS 2016 Front. We have a general purpose ADO connection object that we use to send SQL commands off to our DB. When we have SQL that returns something, we were using code to build a passthru query object, which was a handly way to get SQL output into the frontend.

We are now in a situation where we have some really complex SQL that returns an output, but consists of several statements, including the construction of several temp tables on the server. We can't use the "build a passthru query object" method because passthrus can't handle multiple SQL Statements, and we can't send the SQL statements one at a time because the temp tables get destroyed after the query finishes.

At present, we are now using our ADO objects to get the output into an ADO recordset, then saving the recordset down as an .XML and then finally importing the .XML file into the DB. But this is a lot of I/O and it goes slow for large outputs.

Is there any better (faster) way to get the output of our complex SQL into a local table in the MS Access Frontend?

Heres a snippit of our vba class object:

```
Private Const DB_CONNECTION_STRING As String = "<our connection string>"

Private conn As ADODB.Connection
Private cmd As ADODB.Command
Private recAff As Long
______________________________________________________________
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

conn.Open DB_CONNECTION_STRING

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandTimeout = 0
End With
End Sub
...
<more properties/methods>
...
Public Sub LocalizeOutput(fetchSQL As String, InputTableName As String)
'If the InputTableName does not exist, a new table will be created. All fields will be datatyped as Text
'Otherwise, if the InputTableName does exist, data will be appended. Caller is responsible for handling errors

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim XMLFilePath As String
Dim domIn As Object
Dim domOut As Object
Dim domStylesheet As Object

XMLFilePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\TableImport.xml"
fetchSQL = "SET NOCOUNT ON; " & vbNewLine & fetchSQL

Set domIn = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
domIn.async = False

'Execute the query
With cmd
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = fetchSQL
    Set rs = .Execute(recAff)
End With

Dim tbl As TableDef

'Save off the output as xml file
If FileExists(XMLFilePath) Then
    Call FileDelete(XMLFilePath)
End If
rs.Save XMLFilePath, adPersistXML

'Write the XML Transformation File
Call WriteXSLTransform(InputTableName)

'Convert the ado_xml file into an Access readable xml file
domIn.Load XMLFilePath

Set domStylesheet = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
domStylesheet.Load Environ("TEMP") & "\ADOXMLToAccess.xsl"

Set domOut = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
domIn.transformNodeToObject domStylesheet, domOut

'Set domIn = Nothing
Call FileDelete(XMLFilePath)

'Save the output
domOut.Save XMLFilePath

'Import the saved document into Access
Application.ImportXML XMLFilePath, acAppendData

'clean up
Call FileDelete(XMLFilePath)
Call FileDelete(Environ("TEMP") & "\ADOXMLToAccess.xsl")
Set rs = Nothing
Set domIn = Nothing
Set domOut = Nothing
Set domStylesheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: StoredProcedures won't work for you?

Comment: Stored Procedure -> Passthrou -> "make table query"...?

Comment: You guys are right. SP is the way to go here. Thanks for helping me get to what should have been the obvious answer.